# Do I ever want to install a package outside of a sandbox?

Tags: haskell, cabal

After 3 months of using Haskell, I just realized that I shouldn't use cabal as a package manager.

Now my question is do I ever want to install a package outside of a sandbox? If yes, why?

Comment: I prefer `cabal` for the xmonad installation. This way I have a fresh package, that will be installed without any errors (for example, the installation xmonad with `emerge` caused an dependencies error on my Gentoo)

Comment: I only have `ghc-mod`, `hlint` and `hasktags` installed in my user db. Those are development tools I use in all my sandboxes, so I don't need to install them every time I create a sandbox.

Comment: Haskell is the most beautiful programming language ever. cabal is ssssssssssssssllllllllllllllllllloooooooooooooooooowwwwwwwwwwwwwwww, complicated, ugly, frustrating, fault-intolerant and flaky. I wish it were fast, reliable, simple, pretty and pleasant. Sometimes I just give up installing stuff. Always I dread it.

Comment: like @DannyNavarro I install executable packages globally (have ~/.cabal/bin in my path), other than that I'd like to disable them. Well except for the fact that then playing with packages in GHCi, outside of a cabal project, becomes difficult. Still haven't found a good solution there.

Comment: @jberryman I usually do a `cabal get`, then create a sandbox in the directory with the downloaded source and then `cabal repl`. When I'm done playing with it I delete the whole directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I often muck around with ideas that aren't full packages.  They're often a single file, around 30-100 lines, don't have a `main`, aren't libraries, and are never intended to be used as anything other than toys to load in ghci.  Occasionally, they depend on libraries from packages that don't come with ghc.  I'll just install packages they depend on in my user db, because who cares?  Worst case, I'll nuke `~/.ghc` and reinstall what I need for whatever I work on next.